# how to manipulate linkedlist and also accepts user input of different data type?

Tags: java, input, linked-list

it is a java code.i have to created a link list but i am having issues in manipulating it. in terms of how to accept any user input in terms of data type be it integer or string. and also how to save several information in one node. and also how to display whats saved in the linked list.
sorry for my English.

Comment: I see this is you first Question on Stack Overflow, welcome! Please provide some code so we can we can understand the context of your question, which in turn will help us out to help you. Also see [How To ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask better question which lead to better answers.